# “I'm dying everyday...” vs. "I've been dying everyday..."

Tags: meaning, difference, present-continuous

Are these sentences grammatically correct and do they convey same meaning as they appear?

> 1. I'm dying everyday waiting for my result.
> 2. I've been dying everyday waiting for this moment for many many years.

Answer (score 3):

"...do they convey [the] same meaning as they appear [to]?" ... yes, they mean exactly what they say. In both of them, **dying** means, quite literally, getting closer to death: nothing more.

If you want to express the meaning **to be extremely eager**, you need to use the expressions [**dying to..** or **dying for..**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-dying-for-to-do-sth?q=dying%20for).

It is usually used to emphasize the strength of a wish at a particular time:

> I am **dying** to hear my result.
>   I am **dying for** a cup of tea!

It can be used to describe a long period, but generally only using a relatively approximate phrasing like **for ages**, for example:

> I have been **dying to** meet you for ages!

Note that you have to use two words for **every day**, otherwise it means this: [everyday](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/everyday).